# Is bounds checking in C or C++ expensive?

Tags: c++, c

> Bound checking is expensive
>   (> x2 times runtime overhead)

I got this point above from one of my professors. I am confused about that. 
As I know, the most time-consuming part of a program is IO(from network and from hard disks).

But bounds checking in C or C++ are not always related with those 2 input sources.
For example, I copy the content of one buff to another in C using `memcpy(dest, src, length(src))`. Before that, I check the size of `src` in order to prevent from a heap overflow. The precess I can image is: Get the start-address of `src` and the `\x00` byte in `src`(in the view of assembly language, I copy the content of `src` one by one and see if the byte is equivalent with `\x00`). After getting the 2 address, just substract them to get the length of `src`. I read the content of `src` from the memory. We all know reading things from memory is fast.

Answer (score 10):

I just ran a program I had with iterator bounds checking turned on.

The running time went from 789 ms to 2608 ms.

So yes, it can matter. Not all the time, but certainly more than never.

In particular, bound-checked iterators require at least twice as much storage as simple pointers, and furthermore, are not as easily optimized. In theory they're simple and efficient, but in practice you simply don't want to do work that you don't need to.

Oh, and did I mention the *compile* time went from 7.72 seconds to 13.21 seconds as well?

---

For the many nonbelievers among you... a miniature example takes [0.92 seconds without bounds checking](http://ideone.com/Zk3M5U) and [1.96 seconds with](http://ideone.com/9kXCCk).

---

Since there's a lot of skepticism about *everything*, including `vector`'s efficiency... here's another one:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>

template<class T> struct Vector
{
    T *b, *e;
    Vector(size_t n) : b(new T[n]), e(b + n) { }
    T &operator[](size_t i) { return b[i]; }
    T &at(size_t i) { if (i >= e - b) { throw "invalid"; } return b[i]; }
};

#define at operator[]  // Comment this out to enable bounds-checking

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Vector<size_t> v(1 << 16);
    for (size_t *p = v.b; p != v.e; ++p) { *p = 1; }
    clock_t begin = clock();
    for (int j = 0; j < 1 << 12; ++j)
    {
        for (size_t i = 8, n = v.e - v.b; i < n; ++i)
        {
            v.at(i) += v.at(i - 8);
            v.at(i) ^= v.at(i - 7);
            v.at(i) -= v.at(i - 6);
            v.at(i) ^= v.at(i - 5);
            v.at(i) += v.at(i - 4);
            v.at(i) ^= v.at(i - 3);
            v.at(i) -= v.at(i - 2);
            v.at(i) ^= v.at(i - 1);
        }
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    fprintf(stderr, "%u\n", clock() - begin);
}
```

#### [2.09 seconds](http://ideone.com/MUuq71) vs. [0.88 seconds](http://ideone.com/oJcxzN).

Comment: In many applications, such as safety critical, bounds checking is required, regardless of the extra speed or space.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Yes, and in those applications, you wouldn't be asking this question in the first place.

Comment: I'd mention _why_ it makes it slower, too. Specifically, GCC 4.9 with `-Ofast` unrolls the unchecked code, but not the checked code. Pass in [`-fno-tree-loop-optimize`](http://mailman.cs.huji.ac.il/pipermail/linux-il/2009-December/003402.html) and they suddenly run at the same speed (which, because of some additional missed optimizations, is much slower than even the checked code originally was).

Comment: @StuartOlsen: It's interesting that it may be the case for this particular example, but as you probably realize, it's just an example of a particular optimization being missed, while as a general rule, bounds checking is measurably slower even without particular/specific optimizations. The project I originally ran it on was *way* more complicated than anything that would derive its benefit solely from a single optimization; the sole purpose of this example to prove once and for all that the scenario isn't as far-fetched as people seem to believe, and in fact occurs in pretty trivial programs.

Comment: @Mehrdad If it's _just_ an example of a particular optimization being missed, doesn't that indicate that the bounds checking _itself_ isn't significantly expensive? I mean, the end result is the same, so it's more interesting than practically useful, but if optimizer technology is to continue to be improved to the point that bounds checking is generally practical, this is important to know (and there's definitely room to improve; there's enough information available about `i` to elide all the checks in this code entirely, and I'm honestly surprised that it doesn't).

Comment: @StuartOlsen: I mean, I specifically mentioned in my answer that bound-checked code is harder to optimize, which was aimed precisely at the kind of scenario you just described. It doesn't really matter that optimizers are getting better and better -- it's not like they can solve the halting problem. And not all loops do nice i++ increments anyway. It's not exactly difficult to make a loop the compiler can't optimize, but I'm not going to waste time doing that because it misses the larger point I tried to make with the answer: that bound checking *can* indeed cause 2x slowdown as a consequence.

Comment: @Mehrdad What you've demonstrated isn't that bound checking can cause a 2x slowdown; you've shown that it can _prevent_ a 2x speedup in what you rightly pointed out is a limited subset of loops. Again, the end result is the same in _this_ particular code, but not necessarily in the case when there are no special optimizations for the check to defeat. In any case, "can" is a metric of limited usefulness; one can make code arbitrarily bad with or without bound checks. Bound checks may very well make code slower in the common case (i.e., the important one), but this does not demonstrate that.

Comment: @StuartOlsen: You can word it however you want, the end result is the end result. Slowing things down and preventing their speedup don't have a meaningful difference to me. To me, a penny saved is a penny earned. You can disagree.

Comment: @Mehrdad As for optimizers: I can think of a lot of things that "matter," and _most_ of them can't solve the halting problem. Optimizers are among them. As for the end result: yes, it is the end result -- and only that. It is not evident that it is at all indicative of the performance impact of bound checks in the general case. To be perfectly clear, I'm not disputing that it shows that bound checks _can_ cause slowdown. I'm saying that that demonstration alone does little to address the broad question.

Comment: @StuartOlsen: Well, then ignore the demo. I think it's convincing, but obviously you don't, and I didn't intend it to convince every single person in the world either (some people just can't be convinced by anything, period). In fact I didn't even originally have it there precisely because I didn't think it was necessary (or sufficient). It's just a supplement and I welcome you to ignore it if you don't think it supports the answer. It's not like I can force you to draw a conclusion different than the one you want to draw.

Comment: @mehrdad the problem is that almost anything can cause optimizers to mess up. Turning two ifs into an else if can prevent SIMD from kicking in, but to say else if makes optimization harder would be leaping to conclusions. Microbenchmarks tend to mislead (http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html). Remember, the question was "is bounds checking expensive" not "can they cause a slowdown". Others have found it is not to be expensive, which is the correct answer: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ricom/2006/07/12/cost-of-array-bounds-checking-one-experiment/

Answer (score 3):

That used to be true—up until the 1980s.

With modern code generation and highly pipelined CPU architectures, bounds checking can be done for zero or very little additional execution cost.  This is because the bounds check can occur in parallel with memory fetch.

Comment: Don´t want to start a full discussion here too, but "it´s better than in 1980" doesn´t mean anything. Neither "it can´t be improved" nor "it make little difference compared to the whole program".

Comment: Also, "can occur in parallel" does not necessarily imply that compilers can always successfully schedule instructions such that it "does occur in parallel"... And even if it can schedule them well, the fact is that `array[n] = v` can often compile to a single instruction without bounds checking but probably requires half a dozen or more with bounds checking, and some subset of those additional instructions must be executed and retired, which results in a measurable increase in runtime, whether portions of them can run in parallel or not...

Comment: Have you considered that reading the maximum bound of the array may well involve a memory fetch too? I

Comment: Considering that billions of embedded processors are made each year, often with boutique compilers and not so highly pipelined architecture, bounds checking in C is still a big impact in 2014.  There are many factors to consider.

Comment: @Roddy If the access is in a loop, then the bound is mostly likely cached in a register through renaming, at least in L1 cache in a x86 processor.